# Cannot upload image into mysql database use php

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to upload a image to MySQL databases using php5 script. And I am receiving an notice error.

Error, query failed

UploadImage.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Image Upload</TITLE>
</HEAD>
 
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="f1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="uploadImage2.php" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td> Image Upload Page </td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type="file" name="imgfile"/></td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/> </td></tr>
</table>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

UploadImage2.php

```html
<?php 
include "dbconfig.php";
 
$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusr, $dbpass) or die("Error Occurred-".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbconn) or die("Unable to select database");
 
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_FILES['imgfile']['size'] > 0)
{
   $fileName   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['name']); // image file name
   $tmpName    = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name']; // name of the temporary stored file name
   $fileSize   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['size']); // size of the uploaded file
   $fileType   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['type']); //
  
  
   $fp   = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); // open a file handle of the temporary file
   $imgContent  = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName)); // read the temp file
   $imgContent  = mysql_real_escape_string($imgContent);
   fclose($fp); // close the file handle
 
          $query = "INSERT INTO img_tbl (img_name, img_type, img_size, img_data )
                        VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$imgContent')";
           
          mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_errno($dbconn) . ": " . mysql_error($dbconn) . "\n");
          $imgid = mysql_insert_id(); // autoincrement id of the uploaded entry
          //mysql_close($dbconn);
 
          echo "<br>Image successfully uploaded to database<br>";
          echo "<a href=\"uploadImage2_viewimage.php?id=$imgid\">View Image</a>";
 
}else die("You have not selected any image");
?>
```

I have upload an image file but still have error on it.

But now I have counter another error for view Image.

```html
<?php
// get the file with the id from database
include "dbconfig.php";
$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusr, $dbpass) or die("Error Occurred-".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbconn) or die("Unable to select database");

if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{


 $id    = $_REQUEST ['id'];
 $query = "SELECT img_name, img_type, img_size, img_data FROM img_tbl WHERE id = ‘$id’";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 header("Content-length: $size");
 header("Content-type: $type");
 print $content;

 mysql_close($dbconn);
}
?>
```

The error code:

Notice: Undefined variable: id� in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\Testing\uploadImage2_viewimage.php on line 12
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�' at line 1

Please advise...

Comment: please share your db structure

Comment: try to print echo mysql_errno($dbconn) . ": " . mysql_error($dbconn) . "\n";

Comment: What are you getting when print_r($_FILES) , are there any NULL values ?

Comment: I have insert into the print echo at:
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_errno($dbconn) . ": " . mysql_error($dbconn) . "\n");

Error I get:
Error, query failed1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������' at line 2

Comment: Seems that some special characters in $imgContent is breaking the query string , check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ' ' from table fields in query .use this query :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO img_tbl (img_name, img_type, img_size, img_data )
                            VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$imgContent')";
```

also please start to use PDO or mysqli as your query is open for sql injection

Comment: Hi, I still have the same error.. but anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have try it properly but still the same error.. advise.. and thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO `img_tbl` 
(`img_name`, `img_type`, `img_size`, `img_data` )
VALUES
('".$fileName."', '".$fileType."', '".$fileSize."', '".$imgContent."')
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some special characters in `$imgContent` is breaking the query string

Please use `mysql_real_escape_string` to format your data before sending to the database

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
 $fileName   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['name']); // image file name
 $tmpName    = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name']; // name of the temporary stored file name
 $fileSize   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['size']); // size of the uploaded file
 $fileType   = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['imgfile']['type']); //


 $fp   = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); // open a file handle of the temporary file
 $imgContent  = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName)); // read the temp file
 $imgContent  = mysql_real_escape_string($imgContent);
 fclose($fp); // close the file handle
```

**UPDATE**

If the first solution didn't fix the problem , please check are there any NULL values , you have some database columns which set to NOT NULL . so you cannot insert NULL values to them .

Hope this helps :)